# How to create signature in Jenga API with asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to get the transaction details using Jenga API, but for that we need to send signature in the headers. does anyone have any idea how to create signatures in asp.net core or c#.

Comment: What have you tried so far

Comment: i am using this link for reference https://developer.jengaapi.io/docs/generating-signatures. But it has examples only for python and PHP